# Esterification and dehydration synthesis

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

I know there are many more terms out there like polymerization, condensation, etc. But the important thing is whether they can be differentiated or not.

In Esterification, which I just learned, needs to have a dehydrating agent when involving bad leaving group, such as $\ce{-OH}$.They are typically Brønsted-Lowry acids. Correct me if I'm wrong.

How does heterolysis work in the case of $\ce{CH3COOC2H5}$. [the reverse of the esterification of ethanoic acid and ethanol]

Comment: You must mention the medium in which Esterification/Hydrolysis is happening : Acidic/Basic.

Answer (score 3):

The reverse of esterification is called "hydrolysis."  The hydrolysis reaction can be performed under acidic or basic conditions.  This [link](http://www.chem.ucalgary.ca/courses/350/Carey5th/Ch20/ch20-3-3-1.html) shows the mechanisms involved for both the acidic and basic hydrolysis of an ester.  Each step in the reaction is explained in detail and accompanied by a picture.